# How to use two pre-filtering ( with CRMAF_ ) in one report in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to use two pre-filtering in CRM at one report.

I create report with Visual Studio. For example, I want that "cooperative report" filtered organization ( `CRMAF_FilteredAccount` ) and if I run this report from "Contracts" - filtered ContractID ( `CRMAF_FilteredContract` ).

A dataset for the first parametr:

```
SELECT      CRMAF_Filtereduds_space.uds_spaceid
FROM          dbo.Filtereduds_space
         as CRMAF_Filtereduds_space
```

and for the second:

```
SELECT      CRMAF_FilteredContract.ContractId
FROM          dbo.FilteredContract
         as CRMAF_FilteredContract
```

But I have error when I run report from "Contract".

When it runs from "Organizations" - it's ok.

I start trace that show error: server should not create a query plan and that all.

If I delete one of this parameter - it's ok.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "CRMAF_" in select statement.

This answer may help you.

Comment: But I have to...If I don't use "CRMAF_" ,I won't have pre-filtering. User want to substitute contract number in filter for don't selecting from common list before show all report. Also he want the same from Organization. And it must be one report. If I made a copy, it's ok. Because I use only one "CRMAF_"....

Comment: I am taking about select statement

Comment: SELECT      CRMAF_Filtereduds_space.uds_spaceid

Comment: It's look like
SELECT      uds_spaceid
FROM          dbo.Filtereduds_space
         as CRMAF_Filtereduds_space